# Issue with sorting in pandas column in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code.

I am trying to sort the values of the first column of the 'happydflist' dataframe in ascending order.

However, the output this gives me includes some values such as '2','3' and '8' that do not fit in with the ascending order theme.

```
happydflist = happydflist[happydflist.columns[0]]
happydflistnew = happydflist.sort_values(ascending=True)
print(happydflistnew)

12    13
10    19
13     2
11    24
15     3
6     33
24    35
8     36
5     37
25    49
17    49
20    50
26    51
22    52
16    52
18    52
19    52
28    53
27    54
23    54
21    59
9     74
7     75
14     8
Name: 0_happy, dtype: object
```

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

'happydflist' looks like this:

```
5     37
6     33
7     75
8     36
9     74
10    19
11    24
12    13
13     2
14     8
15     3
16    52
17    49
18    52
19    52
20    50
21    59
22    52
23    54
24    35
25    49
26    51
27    54
28    53
Name: 0_happy, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your dataframe's dtype of some is `str` so  make that to `int` instead.

```
happydflist.astype('int').sort_values()
```

if you need `str` dtype use `astype` 1more so:

```
happydflist.astype('int').sort_values().astype('str')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion! It tells me: cannot convert float NaN to integer - but I'm not sure why :(

Comment: maybe there is NaN in your full data. Look for converting to numeric when NaN exist. Each of your data is different, so I can't tell you. You may also use `pd.numeric` with `coerce` error.

Comment: there is no 'NaN' in the first column - so I'm not sure why that column doesn't work? does it work for you using my data? :)

Comment: I don't want anyone's data to work. If i gave you idea, you should solve the rest by yourself. The problem is that it is not a numeric type. and your data have something that cant convert to `int` (ex NaN or white space str or and so on...) Try solving it well.

Comment: absolutely - I will try solving it :)

Comment: I have manged to solve it now - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I have posted my solution above :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by using the df.strip() function to remove 'white space' around text in a dataframe, combined with the .dropna() function.

```
    happydflistnew = happydflist[happydflist.columns[0]].str.strip()
    happydflistnew = happydflistnew.dropna()
    happydflistsorted = happydflistnew.astype('int').sort_values(ascending=True)
    maxvalue = len(happydflistsorted) 
    minhappiness = happydflistsorted.iloc[0]
    maxhappiness = happydflistsorted.iloc[maxvalue-1]
```

Comment: use `max` or `min` func for getting `maxhappiness` or `minhappiness`. and accept my answer for someone sorting string instead int :)

Comment: yes! :) all done